# Sort bar plot by month ascending

Tags: python, matplotlib, monthcalendar

grateful for some help here!

I have concat 3 dataframes in Python & Matplotlib each with columns 'date' as datetime64 ex '2020-03-05'. When I Bar plot them, im unable to get month/yeah ascending from left to right"

```
        
    vc = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])
    vc['month_year'] = vc['date'].dt.strftime('%b %Y')
    vc['month_year'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
```

thanks!

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSlOW.png)

Comment: What happens if I sort them in ascending order after calculating the frequency?

Comment: Can you add your output? You can try add to the flag ```ascending=True``` to the ```value_counts()``` method: ```vacancies['MONTH_YEAR'].value_counts(ascending=True).plot(kind='bar')```

Comment: If it's not work try: Or try to change to this: ```vacancies['MONTH_YEAR'].value_counts(ascending=True).sort_values(by='MONTH_YEAR',ascending = True).plot(kind='bar')```

Comment: @EitanRosati adding:
ascending=True just reverse the current order but still doesn't order by month/year from left to right

.sort_values(by='MONTH_YEAR',ascending = True) gets an error "TypeError: sort_values() got an unexpected keyword argument 'by'

but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To show the months in ascending order you can do like that:

1. The `strftime()`return `ndarray` so it has different sort than a datetime object. instead of cast it with `strftime()` cast it to period object: `dt.to_period('M')`.
2. after the `value_counts()` the values are sorted by the count and the `month_year` become the index of this DataFrame. so you need just to sort the index before ploting.

**Your code after changes:**

```
vc = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])
vc['month_year'] = vc['date'].dt.to_period('M')
vc_graph = vc['month_year'].value_counts().sort_index(ascending=True)
vc_graph.index = (vc_graph.index).strftime('%b %Y')
vc_graph.plot(kind='bar')
```

**The output will look like that:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I would like to keep the formatting as 'JAN 2019'. Is that possible ?

Comment: Sure, it's add a little bit more code. I added it in the answer